# I keep getting IEFC452I errors, what's wrong?

Tags: jcl

```
//name JOB 1,NOTIFY=&SYSUID             
//sort01 exec pgm=sort                      
//sysout dd sysout=*                        
//sysprint dd sysout=*                      
//sysudump dd sysout=*                      
//sortin dd disp=shr,dsn=public.data(ascii) 
//sortout dd sysout=*                       
//sysin dd *                                
     sort fields=(1,1,ch,a)
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: @AndySavage in this case it actually means that every single letter is incorrect, except those in uppercase, and that every single line was rejected with one or more additional error-messages not referenced. The actual message code quoted just means "the job did not work due to a JCL error" :-)

Answer (score 1):

The message you are getting is `IEFC452I  text - JOB NOT RUN - JCL ERROR`

The value of `text` will be your userid plus the character(s) you entered when you were asked after the SUBMIT.

If you look at file two of your output, you will see a shedload of other messages.

Your problem is that JCL can only be written in uppercase.

Is this a contest, or a course? We had exactly the same JCL (different problem) a couple of days ago.

If you change everything to uppercase (in the line-number area type uc99 on the first line, and it will "uppercase" the next 99 lines (saving you having to work out how many) and assuming your dataset exists you will be good to go.

As with the other question, for a SORT step, SYSYDUMP and SYSPRINT are irrelevant. Delete those lines.

Also note that you have a SORT Control Card, which is not itself JCL, but also needs to be in uppercase.